# How to Show/Hide menu based on user type using asp.net MVC session

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to show/ hide my navigation menus based in user type retrieved by session. i can get the user type using session but while i check it, its not showing the menu's for any type of users. the following is my code. please help thanks

My session in controller

```
//get user login user ID;
        string uname = User.Identity.Name;
        var obj= db.Users.Where(x => x.Username.Equals(uname)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (obj != null)
        {

            Session["userType"] = obj.UserType;

        }
```

my Navigation Items checked by session

```
@if(Session["userType"]=="1"){
                         <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Projects Management <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "packages", new { ID = "" })">Packages</a></li>
                                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Lot", new { ID = "" })">Lots</a></li>
                                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Projects", new { ID = "" })">Projects</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        }
```

Comment: `Session["userType"]` returns `object`, so you need to cast it - e.g. `@if((int)Session["userType"]==1)`

Comment: thanks, it helped me.